How to call event from imported component in slot?
How to call event in Main component but event is located in imported component?
Main component:


...
  <RTable.Rows key="rows">
    {dataMemo?.map(d => (
      <tr key={d.ml_id}>
    
        <td><input type="checkbox" name={d.ml_id} checked={d.isChecked} onChange={onCheck} /></td>
        <td>{d.email}</td>

      </tr>
    ))}
  </RTable.Rows>
</RTable>



Imported RTable component:


function RTable({ children, isLoading, data, pagination }) {
  const rows = children.find(child => child.key === 'rows')

  const onCheck = (event) => {
  // How to call this function from slot outside

...



I need to check checkboxes for table inside, but i use slot for rows outside
Help please

You can convert the children input as a callback.
    {(onCheck: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>) =>
        dataMemo?.map((d) => (
          <tr key={d.ml_id}>
            ...

Then in the parent component, pass in the onChange property.
function Parent({ children }: any) {
  const onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (
    event: ChangeEvent
  ) => {
    console.log(event, 'from slot');
  };
  return <>{children(onChange)}</>;
}

Full Code:
import { ChangeEvent, ChangeEventHandler, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Parent({ children }: any) {
  const onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (
    event: ChangeEvent
  ) => {
    console.log(event, 'from slot');
  };
  return <>{children(onChange)}</>;
}

function App() {
  const [data] = useState([{ test: 1 }]);
  const [dataMemo] = useState([
    { ml_id: '1', isChecked: false, email: 'test1' },
    { ml_id: '2', isChecked: false, email: 'test2' },
    { ml_id: '3', isChecked: false, email: 'test3' },
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      {data.map(() => (
        <Parent key="rows">
          {(onCheck: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>) =>
            dataMemo?.map((d) => (
              <tr key={d.ml_id}>
                <td>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name={d.ml_id}
                    checked={d.isChecked}
                    onChange={onCheck}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>{d.email}</td>
              </tr>
            ))
          }
        </Parent>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Stackblitz Demo

My situation a little different, i added code in Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-fsxmphst?file=index.html,src%2FApp.jsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FTable.jsx&terminal=dev
check please
